# If $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence in which $a_n \geq c$ for some constant $c$ and $a_n \rightarrow a$ then $a \geq c$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

If  $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence in which $a_n \geq c$ for some constant $c$  and $a_n \rightarrow a$ then $a \geq c$

I just wanted some feedback on whether my proof of the claim is sound.

**Proof**

Let $\epsilon > 0$  and $ a < c$. Now $a_n \rightarrow a$ means:

$$\forall \  \epsilon >0,\ \exists \ N\in \mathbb{N} \ s.t.\ \forall \ n \geq N \ |a_n - a| < \epsilon \\ \Leftrightarrow \\ \ a-\epsilon \leq a_n \leq a + \epsilon$$

Consider $\epsilon = \frac{c-a}{2}$

$$\Rightarrow c \leq a_n \leq a + \frac{c-a}{2} = \frac{a+c}{2} < \frac{c + c}{2} = c$$

$c < c$ is a contradiction. Therefore $a \geq c$ for the statement to hold.

Comment: Your proof is good but as an aside I have to wonder about "$\forall \  \epsilon >0,\ \exists \ N\in \mathbb{N} \ s.t.\ \forall \ n \geq N \ |a_n - a| < \epsilon \\ \Leftrightarrow \\ \ a-\epsilon \leq a_n \leq a + \epsilon$".  This is maybe an editorial comment, but nobody likes to read such symbol soup an it doesn't make math more "serious".  Also what you wrote doesn't parse.  $|a_n-a|<\epsilon\iff a-\epsilon\le a_n\le a+\epsilon$ is *always* true for *all* $n$, $a_n$, $a$ and $\epsilon$.  Does that mean *all* sequences converge to all values?

Comment: Funny you mention that. I was talking to my professor about this same thing this week because I'm not a big fan of the "symbol soup" as you call it and was inquiring whether just communicating my ideas in plain English would be better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is fine but:

- You should not begin with “Let $\varepsilon>0$”. You fix $\varepsilon$ later, not at this point.
- You should write that you are assuming that $a<c$, in order to get a contradiction. You can't just say “Let […] $a<c$”, because $a$ and $c$ are fixed from the start.

Comment: Should I state it in terms of: "assume $a < c$ towards a contradiction....."? And with regards to $\epsilon$ don't I have to declare at the start that it will always be positive?

Comment: This is a matter of taste, but I would begin with “In order to get a contradiction, let us assume that $a<c$”. Concerning the other question, note that you wrote right after $\forall\varepsilon>0$. So, no, you don't have to write that.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof seems legitimate to me, but it is a proof by contradiction, so here is an alternate way to do it directly. I will start with what you have.

$$\forall \  \epsilon >0,\ \exists \ N\in \mathbb{N} \ s.t.\ \forall \ n \geq N \ |a_n - a| < \epsilon \\ \Leftrightarrow \\ \ a-\epsilon \leq a_n \leq a + \epsilon$$

Now, this implies that for any $\epsilon > 0$, $a_n \leq a+\epsilon$ for some $n \in \Bbb{N}$. Also, $c \leq a_n$, so we get $c\leq a+\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon > 0$. Thus, $c\leq g$ for all real numbers $g$ in the interval $(a, \infty)$. It is well known that $a$ is the greatest lower bound for $(a, \infty)$, so this implies $c \leq a$.